# jQuery: offset() animation and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easing

I'm having a little problem with jQuery ajax and an animation.
I have a layout with a menu that call my page and when loaded, provide a little animation with `jQuery easing`

Here's my `ajax.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Ajax request
    $(".transition").click(function() {
      page = ( $(this).attr("id") );
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: page,
        data: "ajax=true",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          afficher(html);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrows) {
          // Erreur durant la requête
        }
      });
    });

    function afficher(donnees) {
      $(".step").empty();
      $(".step").append(donnees);

      // Animate
      var step_position = $(".step").offset();
      $(".step").offset({ top: step_position.top, left: step_position.left - 1000 });
      $(".step").animate({
          "left": '+=1000',
        }, 750, 'easeOutBack');
    }
});
```

If a user clicks, everything work great.

But if:

- A user double clicks on the same link
- A user clicks fast on several links

then the loaded data goes out of the page.

I know there's a problem with the fact that I work with asynchronous data and that I ask for the `offset` at a precise time. I tried to put constant as parameters (instead of doing `var step_position = $(".step").offset();` ) but that didn't work.

How should I do for always displaying my data correctly, no matter how many ajax calls are made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moi aussi!

Yep had the same problem - it's called a race condition. I had a button - I don't know if you are using one?

What I did was in the click handler the first thing I did was disable the button by using the JQUERY `.attr()` function - adding the disable attribute.

This had the effect of preventing the second click from doing anything. I re-enabled the button when the ajax came back with a result. In this case you'll have to use a callback somewhere after the animation to reenable the button.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but then the user has to wait for the page to load before he can click anything else. If he misclicks, he has to wait: that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar. I defined a global var that checks if a ajax call is still being treated or not. Doesn't solve my problem of a "fluid navigation" (see my previous comment), but that'll do. Anyways, I'll accept your answer in few days if nobody came with something different. Thanks !

Comment: You can set a timeout for the JQUERY ajax call, and preferably a (slightly) shorter timeout on the server, if you don't want the user to wait too long.